# Iterating in to the set of strings which are the values in map

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void insertValue(map<string, set<string> >& myMap,
    string const& key,
    string const& value)
{
    // Check whether there is already a set given the key.
    // If so, insert to the existing set.
    // Otherwise, create a set and add it to the map.
    map<string, set<string> >::iterator found = myMap.find(key);
    if (found != myMap.end())
    {
        cout << "Adding '" << value << "' to an existing set of " << key << "s.\n";
        found->second.insert(value);
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Adding '" << value << "' to a new set of " << key << "s.\n";
        set<string> temp;
        temp.insert(value);
        myMap.insert(make_pair(key, temp));
    }
}

int main()
{
    map<string, set<string> > filemap;
    insertValue(mymap, "file1", "path1");
    insertValue(mymap, "file1", "path2");
    insertValue(mymap, "file1", "path3");
    insertValue(mymap, "file2", "path1");
    insertValue(mymap, "file3", "path2");
    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone tell me how I can iterate through the set of strings, given a key in the above map????  or do I have to place an iterator in the value ....I can't understand how can I go this this further

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to iterate over the `map` is by using a range-based `for` instead of using iterators

```
for(auto const& kv : mymap) {
    for(auto const& v : kv.second) {
        std::cout << kv.first << ": " << v << '\n';
    }
}
```

`kv` is a `const&` to your map's `value_type`, which is `std::pair<const std::string, std::set<std::string>>`. The nested `for` statement is then iterating over the second element in the `pair`.

And if you really want to use iterators, then use this

```
for(auto miter = mymap.cbegin(); miter != mymap.cend(); ++miter) {
    for(auto siter = miter->second.cbegin(); siter != miter->second.cend(); ++siter) {
        std::cout << miter->first << ": " << *siter << '\n';
    }
}
```

---

That aside, your function for inserting values can be simplified quite a bit. There's no need to check whether an element already exists in a `map` before inserting a value because `map::operator[]` will construct the key you pass to it if one doesn't already exist, and the corresponding value type will be value initialized. So your `insertValue` function becomes a one-liner.

```
void insertValue(map<string, set<string> >& myMap,
    string const& key,
    string const& value)
{
    myMap[key].insert(value); // default construct a set for a new key
}
```

---

Finally, unless you need the values corresponding to a key be ordered, you can use a [`multimap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap) instead. This container is just like a `map`, but you can have several values corresponding to a single key value. However, unlike your solution, the order of the values which have identical keys is the order of their insertion.

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/316f065fea393d30)